# Very wide graphics in knitr HTML

Tags: html, css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using r markdown and Rstudio to create an html report.  I have some graphics that I would like to be extremely wide, however, there seems to be a limit to the width in the output even when using `fig.width` and `out.width` in the chunk options.  For instance the following three code chunks produce  figures which are the same width in the final output:

````
```{r,fig.height=7,fig.width=12,echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(1000),type="l")
```

```{r,fig.height=7,fig.width=40,echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(1000),type="l")
```

```{r,fig.height=7,fig.width=40,echo=FALSE,out.width=20000}
plot(rnorm(1000),type="l")
```
````

I have used `options(width=LARGENUMBER)` for output (e.g. such as `print`, etc.) which seems to work well for printing tables, but I have yet to find a a way to make these graphs any wider.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add something like this

````
---
output: html_document
---

<style>
img {
    max-width: none;

    /* other options:
    max-width: 200%;
    max-width: 700px;
    max-width: 9in;
    max-width: 25cm;
    etc
    */
}
</style>


```{r,fig.height=7,fig.width=12,echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(1000),type="l")
```

```{r,fig.height=7,fig.width=40,echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(1000),type="l")
```

```{r,fig.height=7,fig.width=40,echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(1000),type="l")
```
````

or better yet set up your knitr.css file with

```
img {
    max-width: 200%;
}
```

or whatever you like, and use

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    css: ~/knitr.css
---
```

Comment: This also works outside of Rstudio using `knit2html`.  Thanks very much!